# Can't load library path files

Tags: files, theming

I have added a library to the libraries folder. I have the Libraries API module installed and I wrote this code:

```
function my_module_libraries_info() {
  $libraries['google-api-php-client'] = array(
    'name' => 'Google Api PHP Client',
    'path' => 'src/Google',
    'vendor_url' => 'https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client',
    'download_url'=> 'https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client',
    'files' => array(
      'php' => array(
        'Client.php',
        'Service.php',
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

and the code to call it

```
$library =libraries_load('google-api-php-client');
dpm($library);
```

This dpm did give me a library array, so it looked like it was ok. But then I tried

```
$client = new Google_Client();
```

and I got an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'http://[site-name-here]/sites/all/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php'
```

When I tried this

```
 global $base_root;
  require $base_root . '/'. libraries_get_path('google-api-php-client') . '/src/Google/Client.php';
```

I got the same error message. I checked and saw tat the files were still there. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache might help. I had tried to use libraries_flush_caches but that didn't seem to work. General CC did though - that will ensure libraries_load detects and loads the files you put in your files array.

Also, for this library (at least composer version "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta") , you want to put 'autoload.php' in your files array - it'll do what it sounds like, auto-load all the classes you want to use instead of you manually having to do it.